# How to get physical path knowing the path to the exe file?

Tags: powershell

How can I get the physical path to an item if I know path of the `.exe` file?

Example:

```
$path = (Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = 'Name of Service'").PathName

cd $path #and this command not work because $path return path with service name
```

Comment: Example of path name value: `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Removes all characters after the file extension and trims double quotes if it finds any:

```
$p = ($path -replace '^"+([^\.]+\.\w+)\s.+$','$1').Trim('"')
cd (Split-Path $p)
```

Get the directory of the file with the Split-Path cmdlet

```
 cd (Split-Path $path -Parent)
```

The Parent parameter is the default split location parameter so you can leave it out:

```
 cd (Split-Path $path)
```

Comment: This will not work. Example of path value is C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs@

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

**Update** The regex will remove the PathName arguments and just give you the file path.

```
$service = gwmi -class Win32_Service | ? {$_.Name -eq "Name of Service"} 
$path = ($service | Select -Expand PathName) -replace "(.+exe).*", '$1'
cd (Split-Path $path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you unless you hava a space in the path:

```
$k = "C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs@"
(gci $k.Split()[0]).Directory.FullName
```